Are these SOL formulas correct?
I need to know if these formulas are correct in the SOL "language" and if my "translations" of them are correct, more examples of easy to understand SOL formulas are also appreciated.
(1) $X$ is a property, $\sigma$ is the successor function and $c$ is the number $0$: $\forall X(Xc \ \land \ \forall x(Xx \ \land \ X \sigma (x)) \to \forall x \ Xx)$ means, "given a property $X$, if $0$ holds that property and, given a variable $x$, if $x$ holds that property and the successor of $x$ holds that property, then every number $x$ holds that property" (Induction)
(2) $P$ is a proposition: $\forall P (P \ \lor \ (\sim P))$ means, "given a proposition $P$, $P$ is true or the negation of $P$ is true" (Excluded middle)
(3) $P$ is a proposition with true value: $\forall P (\sim (\sim P))$ means, "given a proposition $P$ with true value, the negation of the negation of $P$ is true" (Double negation)
(4) $P$ is a proposition, $T$ is the property of being true and $F$ is the property of being false: $\forall P (TP \ \lor \ FP)$ means, "given a proposition $P$, $P$ holds the property of being true or $P$ holds the property of being false" (Bivalence)
(5) $P$ and $Z$ are propositions: $\forall PZ((P \ \land \sim P) \to Z)$ means, "given two propositions $P$ and $Z$, if $P$ and the negation of $P$ is true, then $Z$ is true"
(6) $H$ is the property of being human, $C$ is the property of being a cat and $L$ is the property of loving: $\forall x(Cx \ \to \ \exists y(Hy \ \land \ Lyx))$, means "given $x$, if $x$ is a cat then there exists a $y$ such that $y$ is human and holds the property of loving $x$", or in other words, "all cats are loved by at least one human"

@MauroALLEGRANZA 2-5 aren't SOL even with quantifiers over generic propositions? And I wonder if (6) could be changed to $\nexists A \subset C \ \forall xy((Hx \ \land \ Ay) \ \to \ \sim(Lxy))$ with $C$ being the set of all cats and it would be SOL and meaning "there is not a cat that is not loved"? Thanks.

Long comment
To be pedantic, only (1) is Second-Order and it is the well-known Induction axiom: in it, there is the $∀X$ quantifier, where $X$ is a property.
Formula (6) is First-order: there are no quantifiers acting on property and relation variables.
Formulas (2)-(5) belong to Quantified propositional logic.
